# how to display html content in listview in android?

Tags: java, android

I am developing the android application in whch i need to display html content of  webpages into my list view. I have used simple  adapter to display web content. I am able to retriveing the contents of webpage but problem is it is showing html tag along with content. If you have any solution please reply.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with below line:

`txtHtmlData.setText(Html.fromHtml(YOUR HTML CONTENT)).toString();`

Comment: ya.am new to android.i dont know how to implement above code in list view .my code is like this                          ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
       ListLivefeedzItems.this, rssItemList,
       R.layout.live_item_list_row, new String[] {
         TAG_LINK, TAG_TITLE, TAG_PUB_DATE,
         TAG_DESRIPTION }, new int[] {
         R.id.page_url, R.id.title, R.id.pub_date,
         R.id.link });

Comment: Where you give data to display, just convert this and then give it to display, it will work. Just check where you are showing the string